# Formatting of output is incorrect?

Tags: javascript, css

**My Code:**

```
document.write('<ul>');
document.write('<li><font color="green">intellectual:</font></li>' + bioEnergy);
document.write('<li><font color="red">emotional:</font></li>' + bioEmot);
document.write('<li><font color="blue">physical: </font></li>' + bioPhy);
document.write('</ul>');
```

**Output:**

```
intellectual:

0.8

emotional:

0.0

physical:

0.0
```

What I need is for it to be formatted like this: `intellectual: 0.8`   etc. I'm not sure how to style the HTML to make this work.

Comment: You're closing your `<li>` tags before you're done writing out the whole line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you mean to do is the following:

```
document.write('<li><font color="green">intellectual:</font> ' +  bioEnergy + '</li>');
document.write('<li><font color="red">emotional: </font> ' + bioEmot + '</li>');
document.write('<li><font color="blue">physical: </font> ' + bioPhy + '</li>');
```

Note the changed order of elements inside each document.write.

**Output:**

```
intellectual: 0.8

emotional: 0.0

physical: 0.0
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes that is what I needed. I had tried that but I didn't put the + after bioEnergy is it was coming up as error. :)

Comment: @Sonya1m If you have got the desired answer, please consider accepting it.